# The app delegate must implement the window property if it wants to use a main storyboard file swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, simulator

I have just developed an app, but when running in the simulator the debugger console says:

> The app delegate must implement the window property if it wants to use
>       a main storyboard file.

I have an app delegate file. What does the message mean, and how can I get my app working?

Comment: That question is very hard to understand. Can you try to improve it?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. But from what you provided, I may ask : did you have the `var window: UIWindow?` property in your AppDelegate class ?

Comment: This is the error message that Xcode spits out in the console

Comment: Check your appDelegate class, It should be the subclass of UIResponder.  If your app-delegate is subclass of UIApplication. Please check it once again.

Comment: I encounter this issue today for the first time took me more than 2 hours to fix, but I think I got the final fix. Mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71230252/11690901

Answer (score 198):

Make sure you have the following property declaration in your AppDelegate class:

```
var window: UIWindow?
```

Comment: How come just declaring a property resolved the issue! Developers are crazy indeed.

Answer (score 131):

If you run your project on earlier than iOS 13.0, in that case you will face the problem. Because of iOS 13 and later, app launch differently than earlier versions.

- In iOS 13 and later, use `UISceneDelegate` objects to respond to life-cycle events in a scene-based app
- In iOS 12 and earlier, use the `UIApplicationDelegate` object to respond to life-cycle events.

When you launch the app in iOS 12 and earlier then `UIApplicationMain` class expect a window property in your `AppDelegate` class as like `SceneDelegate` has. So your problem will be solved if you add the following line in your `AppDelegate` class.

```
var window: UIWindow?
```

For Objective-C

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
```

You can find more here [App's Life Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle).

Comment: I wrote this line in AppDelegate class and i changed Main Interface (Target ->General ->Main Interface = Main.storyboard. Still i am getting same .Xcode version  is 11.0 .How to fix it

Comment: Could you please share your crush log?

Comment: input file 'CustomTabBar.swift' was modified during the build
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: But your log says you modified your code when building your project. Clean your build folder (Command+Shif+K). Hope your problem will be resloved.

Comment: Yeah it's done ..May be Xcode 11 is some slow in device .Thanks

Comment: For Objective-C, add the property to the AppDelegate.h file.

Comment: yep, this should be the right answer, with the explanation of why it is needed :D thanks!

Answer (score 34):

Just in case anyone comes across this again and is programming in Objective-C make sure you have this line of code in your `AppDelegate.h` file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
```

Answer (score 32):

I have received this error, when I created new project in XCode 11. I have not used `SwiftUI`. Here are the steps, I have considered to fix this.

1. Deleted `Application Scene Manifest` entry from `Info.plist`
2. Deleted `SceneDelegate.swift` file
3. Deleted all scene related methods in `AppDelegate.swift` class
4. added `var window: UIWindow?` property in `AppDelegate.swift` class

After these steps, I am able to run the app on version prior to iOS 13.

[EDIT]
Finally, your `AppDelegate.swift` file should look something like the following.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: If you're not using swiftUI this should be the correct answer worked for me. Thanks @Sarvan

Comment: This is a workaround to make a regression to the old AppDelegate session, not a solution.

Answer (score 12):

Add the following window declaration in Appdelegate file

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    var window:UIWindow?
    ...
```

***Implementation of this property is required if your app’s Info.plist file contains the UIMainStoryboardFile key.**
The default value of this synthesized property is nil, which causes the app to create a generic UIWindow object and assign it to the property. If you want to provide a custom window for your app, you must implement the getter method of this property and use it to create and return your custom window.*

Comment: Very nice explanation and this solution is working fine in `Xcode 13 & iOS 15`.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, just add `var window: UIWindow?` as the debug error says.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check your app delegate class:

```swift
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**BuildTime Error**

> The app delegate must implement the window property if it wants to use a main storyboard file

Swift 5 & Xcode 11

Make sure that `SceneDelegate` contains `UIWindow` property

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    //...
}
```

Comment: Fair enough - except mine does and still has the error. I'll upvote since it is at least applicable.

Answer (score 3):

Setting in Info.plist
Application Scene Manifest > Enable Mutliple Windows > false.
This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Long ago answered, but to help understand the questions above about why simply adding the window property solves the problem, note that the app delegate conforms to the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol which defines a property, `@property (nullable, nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;` that classes need to provide to specify the `window to use when presenting a storyboard`. Failure to provide that is causing the Xcode log warnings.

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift:**

```
var window: UIWindow?
```

**For Objective-C:**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you might have an `Application Scene Manifest` entry in your `Info.plist` file - if you do not use scenes, but only a window and view controllers (eg because you want to test something in the old UI setup), you should remove that entry to be able to see your views.