# why my app becomes dark when I set deployment target to 11.0 in Xcode 12.1?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode12

I am creating a new project using latest Xcode (12.1). the default deployment target when I create  a new project was 14.1. then I change it to be 11.0. because I want to target users from iOS 11.0 and above

[image]

then it will create a lot of warnings like this in my `AppDelegate` and `SceneDelegate`

[image]

I fix all of them so my `AppDelegate` and `SceneDelegate` will be like the code below.

the problem is.....

when I run it on my real device iOS 14.1, it will have no issue. but when I run it on my iOS 12.4.8 , my app will completely dark

I have also already turn off the dark mode in info.plist using this key

```
<key>Appearance</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

how to solve this ?

completely dark like this iOS 12.4.8 .the background colour should be custom orange
[image]

SceneDelagate.swift

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    }

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
        // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
        // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
        // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not necessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
    }

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
        // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
    }

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
        // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
    }

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
        // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
        // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
        // to restore the scene back to its current state.
    }


}
```

AppDelegate.swift

```
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29442163/9605341)

you have to add the following property declaration in your AppDelegate class

```
var window: UIWindow?
```