# Xcode Swift : appDelgate.window! is nil : Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using MBProgressHUD to show a loader, and when acessing the app window the value in nil and the app crashes.
I already imported the MBProgressHUD and created a variable appDelgate equals to UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate, and when accessing that variable window! I get the follwing error: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Code:

```
import MBProgressHUD
let appDelgate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: appDelgate.window!, animated: true)
```

I cant seem to find what I missing here

Comment: Are you running it in iOS 13+?

Comment: Are you using main interface or created a window yourself e.g self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds) in App delegate?

Comment: Yes, i'm using 14.5 @user28434'mstep

Comment: @RTXGamer i'm using in AppDelegate.swift in the main window, basically on the app startup  i'm sending a request to an api ro register a token.

Comment: @bmpf_pt, they've moved `window` to the `scene delegate` in iOS 13.

Comment: @user28434'mstep that option is not available

Answer (score 1):

You have to add var window: UIWindow? property in AppDelegate.swift.
You can refer to this link

[The app delegate must implement the window property if it wants to use a main storyboard file swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441682/the-app-delegate-must-implement-the-window-property-if-it-wants-to-use-a-main-st)